# Why do we differentiate displacement to get velocity if displacement is given as a function of time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differentiation

Like if the displacement is given as S=(2t³)and if we are asked to find the velocity in 2 seconds then if we put t=2 in the expression we get 16 which isn't correct. The correct must be dS/dt=6t² and then if we plug 2 in t we get the velocity as 24. Someone plz explain. Why don't we get the correct answer if we don't differentiate and directly plug the value in the expression which was given?

Comment: If you wanted to know the object's weight (or price) at time 2, would you still "plug into" $2t^3$ ?

Comment: what are dimensions of number `2` - is it $[m/s^3]$ or is it just a dimensionless number ?

Answer (score 2):

It’s because  setting t=2 in the first equation tells you the distance the object goes in 2 seconds, not its velocity after 2 seconds.

I would add, per @Agnius Vasiliauskas, that there should be a statement given with the equation that says the coefficient 2 has units of m/s$^3$ in order to make sense.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your displacement equation is faulty, because left side has dimensions of $[m]$ and right side has dimensions of $[s^3]$ (**dimensions of left and right side of equation must be the same**). Thus it should be $$s = 2At^3$$
where constant $A$ has dimensions of $[m/s^3]$.
In this case speed :
$$ v= \frac{ds}{dt} = 6 A t^2 $$
or variable A is function of time $A=A(t)$ also, then speed is :
$$ v=\frac{ds}{dt} = 2 t^3 \frac{dA(t)}{dt}  + 6 t^2 A(t) $$

In this last case calculus trick is used :
$$ \frac{d}{dk}\big(x(k) \cdot y(k)\big) = y(k) \frac{dx(k)}{dk} + x(k) \frac{dy(k)}{dk} $$

And in general calculus is used in Physics from a long time ago- the point Newton and Leibniz invented it. It's still a main tool in Physics nowadays, so you need to get used to it. Maybe grab some calculus book before jumping to Physical concepts ? Without this knowledge you will loose **a lot** in Physics. My gut feeling is that you strugle to understand speed and other concepts, because of this exact problem. Newton needed it, so you too

Comment: Any reason of downvote ? Because I have explained main physics rule about checking any physics equation correctness ?

Comment: I didn’t down vote, but The equation can be used if you assume (as I did) that the coefficient 2 has units of m/s$^3$. Admittedly it should be stated so.

Comment: Yes, it should be stated as so, because it looks like just dimensionless number.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But it seemed to me the OP’s confusion was with concepts not units

Comment: Now it looks like someone down voted me. Oh well c’est la vie

Comment: Not me, really :-) As for me, I think that explaining speed concept without explaining first dimensional analysis - will do more harm than benefit. I think OP should concentrate on unit dimensions at first. Then understanding physical derivatives will be one step easier to do